# error saving decoded image to the model Django

Tags: python, django, image

I have a base-64 string that I sent to the routes `views.py` and the decode it back using the code

```
image_data = request.POST.get('image_data')
pattern = r'^data:(?P<mime_type>[^;]+);base64,(?P<image>.+)$'
result = re.match(pattern, image_data)
if result:
    mime_type = result.group('mime_type')
    image = result.group('image').decode('base64')
    saveImage = uploadImage(image=image, imageMime=mime_type)
    saveImage.save()
```

Once decoded, I need to save it to the folder in the project and not locally. However when I call .save(), I get an encoding error: `DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte. You passed in '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x`.

Do I need to strip of the PNG part for this to work?

My model is as follows:

```
class uploadImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Gallery')
    imageMime = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `ImageField` to a bytestring; it is expecting a stream object (or a path to a file, IIRC). Try wrapping in a `BytesIO`, e.g.

```
saveImage = uploadImage(image=BytesIO(image), imageMime=mime_type)
```

You will need to `from io import BytesIO` at the top of your views.py.

Comment: I tried that and I get this error: _io.BytesIO' object has no attribute '_committed'